# How to add the item to system clipboard menu?

Tags: android

That is, in addition to select-copy-paste, I need your own item. Not only in my application, but also in others.
Is it real?

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is real take a look at http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/clipboard/copy-paste.html

Answer (score 0):

This is provided by Android 6 and above if your app implements the PROCESS_TEXT intent filter.  For example in your AndroidManifest.xml:

```
<activity android:name="My Romanizer App"
 android:label="Romanize this text">
  <intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.PROCESS_TEXT" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
    <data android:mimeType="text/plain" />
  </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

Then in your onCreate() method, check getIntent().getCharSequenceExtra(Intent.EXTRA_PROCESS_TEXT).toString()

If you want to return replacement text to the app that called you, you'll need to do something like:

```
Intent i=new Intent();
i.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_PROCESS_TEXT, "you have been romanized");
setResult(RESULT_OK, i);
```

and you can detect if sending back a result is appropriate by checking if getIntent().getBooleanExtra(Intent.EXTRA_PROCESS_TEXT_READONLY, false)==false.